Choosing good approach to copy multiple tables in Azure Data Factory
I need to copy hundreds of tables (full or delta) from source to target using Azure Data Factory (ADF). I have two options:
Option A: 1 Pipeline per Table
Pros

Uses native ADF functionality.
Implement full or delta load, specify
source and target.

Cons:

Requires creating 100 pipelines, which is slow / manual due to ADF's
poor UI/UX.

Option B: 1 Dynamic Pipeline
Pros:

Reduces use of ADF UI.

Cons:

Uses a CSV file to control parameters (source, target, copy mode), interpreting each row to execute the pipeline, requires writing custom logic to interpret the file.
Dynamic functions with raw table name strings can be unsafe compared to native functionalities...

Given my preference for native functionalities, I'm leaning towards Option A, but Option B could speed up development (maybe?). Is it valid to expect ADF to support reusable modules for faster development? Which option is better, A or B?

As you mentioned the difference between the two approaches is the speed and performance.

In your scenario, if you opt for cost and performance, then second approach would be better. This approach requires only a single pipeline, and that pipeline runs a loop based on your configuration csv file which will copy all of your source tables to target tables. Whereas the first approach requires hundreds of new pipeline designs and new pipeline runs as well.
In the second approach, you can make the For-loop execution as parallel so that the copying will be done simultaneously. The maximum batch count for this is 50, It means 50 iterations will be executed parallelly.
If there is a need to cast or transform your source tables columns and the data types are not same in the source and target, then first approach would be better as it deals with individual tables through different pipelines.
In the second approach, you can also make use of Upsert option. For this, you need to store the upsert column name in the same csv file. But as you mentioned it less secured compared to your first approach.

AFAIK, I suggest you use second approach with dataset and pipeline parameters if the pipeline design is same for every table as it can reduce the pipeline runs and you can trigger a single pipeline easily.
NOTE: In the second approach, if any two-source table's target is same, this will create conflict of data while executing the For-each activity parallelly. If all target tables are different, then only make the For-loop execution parallel.
